# wp_get_post_terms on custom post type with custom taxonomies returning an empty array

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am trying to get the taxonomy values associated with my custom post types. I have a function which fetches a post ($object)'s taxonomies, then cycles through the taxonomies and gets the values for that post for each taxonomy. At least, that's what I want it to do! Here it is:

```
function get_the_categories($object, $field_name, $request) {

  // I've verified that $object['id'] gives same value as $post->ID equivalent

  $taxonomies = get_post_taxonomies( $object[ 'id' ]);

  // ^ returns ["post_tag","member_of","member_type" ]

  $returnArray = array();
  foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    $val = wp_get_post_terms( $object['id'], $taxonomy, array(
      'fields' => 'name'
    ));
    $returnArray[$taxonomy]=$val;
  }
  return $returnArray;
}
```

The `$taxonomies` query returns three strings, which are the names of my two custom taxonomies. However, the `wp_get_post_terms` query returns an empty array!

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
'fields' => 'name'
```

to

```
'fields' => 'names'
```

If you look at the examples in wordpress documentation you can see you should use plural(names, slugs, ids for fields):
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms#Examples

Comment: Thanks for that spot, but it hasn't fixed my problem :( I'm still getting a response with empty arrays for each value of my $returnArray

Comment: Yeah, one more thing: wp_get_post_terms returns array itself. So if you want to return first term you should use `$returnArray[$taxonomy]=$val[0];`

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that too: I added `$val = isset($val[0]) ? $val[0] : null;` before assigning `$val` to the array and I just get `null`s as values for each array item.

Comment: Do you get any value when you write `echo $val = wp_get_post_terms( 1234, 'book', array( 'fields' => 'names' ));`? With specific post that you know has taxonomies. One reason can be that you havn't create a relationship between taxonomy and post or post type. Another can be the post that you are testing has not any taxonomy term. Just try these and let us know.

Comment: That returns an empty array as well (with my own values).. I was wondering if I have associated the taxonomies properly. I have used the `register_taxonomy` function in the 'init' hook and I can see the custom taxonomies in the admin GUI.. Could anything else be needed? The taxonomy values (eg member_type has 'media', 'race' as options) were all added in the GUI and these are what I'm trying to access.

Comment: OH I think I'm being an absolute moron and querying a backend that has no  values in these taxonomy fields. I'll check this is the case now. If so, your answer will have corrected my code so I will mark is as correct. Thanks for your help